# Simulating a single ended to differential circuit not working as intended

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation

I am trying to simulate the circuit recommended in this [TI article](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa332/sboa332.pdf?ts=1642149452575&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253Dsingle%2Bended%2Bto%2Bdifferential%2526nr%253D14924).

However, my simulations are not matching what is expected. What I am doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential inputs are not at the same DC input and the output is clipping, trying to achieve this.

1. Observe the specs for CM input range
2. Bias accordingly, the  input or the -ve reference or both in this case
3. with high gain, the offset must be chosen wisely

i just read the datasheet and noticed this.

### Edit

***" For proper operation, the input common-mode voltage to the input terminal of the amplifier should not exceed the common-mode input voltage range"***

Your Vocm is at the +ve rail when you want the Vocm to be 0V.  So the outputs were clipped or cut-off.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from however, I am a bit confused why this was recommened in the TI article.